# Setting WiFi up via the command line Ubuntu server 18.04.4 LTS - Raspberry Pi 4 Wireless connectivity

Tags: wifi, pi-4, ubuntu, server

I have the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and my choice of RAM was the 4GB. i don't have internet via the gigabit ethernet at the moment, all i have is my smartphone to share internet via a hotspot (wifi).

i have installed Ubuntu Server 64-bit on the Raspberry 4 following the instructions on the ubuntu official webpage by flashing Ubuntu onto a 128GB samsung microSD card.

The installation went good, but now i want to connect the Raspberry to the internet via the command line to fetch some packages and install the desktop.

How can i setup the wifi via the command line on the Raspberry 4B 4GBRAM?

Comment: [https://netplan.io/examples](https://netplan.io/examples) The above link provides further information on setting up the yaml file for those who have difficulty still.

Comment: Note that the  line indentation is very important here.

Answer (score 7):

To be able to setup Wifi on Raspberry Pi 4 B+ 4GB on Ubuntu server 18 TLS, you first need to get the name of the Wifi card by showing physical components using the following command:

```
 $ sudo lshw
```

in my case it was `wlan0`

Then navigate to `/etc/netplan/` using the `cd command` the hit `Enter`

```
$ cd /etc/netplan/
```

Use the command `ls` to list the files and directories under the folder then  you now have to edit the `.yaml` file:

```
$ sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Finally, add the following lines to the 50-cloud-init file:

```yaml
wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                    "SSID-NAME":
                            password: "WIFI-PASSORD"
            dhcp4: yes
```

***NOTE:** Make sure not to use tab for space, use the spacebar to create the blank.*

Here is the final file code:

```yaml
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
                optional: true
                access-points:
                        "SSID-NAME":
                                password: "WIFI-PASSORD"
                dhcp4: yes
```

Change the `SSID-NAME` and the `WIFI-PASSORD` they have to be in quotes. The `:` after SSID name is required.

Close and save the file using `ctrl`+`x` and `yes`  by tipping the letter `y`

Finally, you need to do some debugs:

```
$ sudo netplan –debug try 
$ sudo netplan –debug generate 
$ sudo netplan –debug apply
```

then reboot the pi

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Install Ubuntu desktop with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```